# Is this valid in first-order modal logic?

Tags: modal-logic

1. (∀x)(∀y){(xEy) --> (∀z)[Tz --> (C(x,z)Ey)]} (Premise)
2. {(∀y)[Ty --> (∃x)(Tx & xEy)]} --> {(∀y)[Ty --> (∃x)(Tx & xEy & ◻(Tx --> Ty))]} (From (1))

I'm trying to work this out in a quantified modal logic system T based on first-order (classical) logic.

Note: 'C' in (1) is a function that symbolizes conjoining, and C(xz) is the product of conjoining x and z. Furthermore, the domain of discourse is restricted to only objects that are propositions (assuming Platonism with respect to propositions).

Comment: What are the details of the system $T$? Different systems yield different validities ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Actually to make things easier let's just use a standard quantified modal logic system S5. As in here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/actualism/SQML.html

Comment: Do you mean SQML? S5 is a system of *propositional* modal logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes SQML, i.e., simplest quantified modal logic (S5).

Comment: FWIW you seem to be conflating SQML and S5, they're not the same thing. S5 is the "propositional part" of SQML, but SQML isn't unique in this regard: there are other ways we could build a quantified modal logic on top of S5.

Comment: What does the "◻" mean before the "(Tx --> Ty)"?  On my computer, it shows up as an unreadable character.

Comment: @user3294068 It's the box operator in modal logics.